# Why grpc repsonds with 403 on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, microservices, grpc-c#

I am trying to use gRPC to communicate between my backend applications built in asp.net core.
When I try my apps offline it works fine and I get a response with each request
the problem is when I upload the server app to IIS and try to send a request it responds with 403 bad gRPC response

my code is simple now I am just messing with the already made example in asp core.
Here is my greeting service

```
 public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
    public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
        {
            Message = "Hello " + request.Name
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcService1";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

and here is the client that sends a request

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The port number(5001) must match the port of the gRPC server.
        using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://grpc.something.com");
        var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
       
        var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(
            new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
        Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Any one got an idea about why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using http or https (secure)?  I think you are sending http and the server requires https.

Comment: @jdweng I am using https and as you see in the client 

        ``` using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://grpc.something.com"); ```

Comment: is your service secured with authentication or authorization?

Comment: @DanielA.White none of them for now

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @jdweng Do I have to use authentication even if I did not implement it in my application?

Comment: You need to login to your linux account.

Comment: @jdweng sorry I did not get what you mean by logging into my account also I am using windows server and IIS

Comment: The credentials have to be setup to make connection.  A client connecting to a server defaults to GUEST account which server can refuse.  So a credential needs to be established for connection to complete.  See the link.

Comment: @jdweng still the same when I have a valid token throws 403 and when I don't it throws 401 which what It should do when I don't have a valid token

Comment: 401 is unauthorized and 403 is forbidden.  So the server still doesn't like the request with 403.  Every server is different. So issue is probably a credential issue in the backend and not in the front end request,